# How to check if opened file is saved on drive - CS6 script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to write function which creates array of files from opened documents, which are located anywhere on a hard drive. 
I don't want files in that array which are not saved anywhere. In other words documents like: file-> new-> create some file->  not save this file anywhere.
I created this code, so far:

```
var docsExistingOnDrive = filteringOpenedDocs();

alert(docsExistingOnDrive);

function filteringOpenedDocs() {

  var imageTypes = [
  /.png$/,
  /.psd$/,
  /.jpg$/,
  /.tif$/,
  /.bmp$/,
  /.gif$/,
  ];

  var openedDocsToProcess = new Array;

  for (var i = 0; i < app.documents.length; i++) {
      for ( var j = 0 ; j < imageTypes.length; j++ ) {
          if ( app.documents[i].name.match(imageTypes[j]) ) {
              openedDocsToProcess.push(app.documents[i]);
          };
      }
  }

  return openedDocsToProcess;
}
```

I noticed that documents not saved yet, do not have any extensions (`png.`, `psd.` etc.) in name. So I used this property to filter files.
 But I also found bug in scenario when user can create file name (*new document*) with extensions (`png.`, `psd.` etc.).
 
Which in result I get false postive result in `if (app.documents[i].name.match(imageTypes[j])` condition. And then it adds a file, which is not saved anywhere on the drive, to the array `openedDocsToProcess`.

===========================================================================

Notes:
 

 
Instead of using `if ( app.documents[i].name.match(imageTypes[j])` condition:

 
1. I tried to use `exists` method in -> `if (app.documents[i].exists)`, but `app.documents[i].exists` gives always `undefined`
2. I tried to use `path` method in -> `app.documents[i].path !== null`, but then I get "*error 8103*" below and script is terminated.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.documents` returns an array of **Document** objects.

This object already has a nifty property for your use-case: `fullName`

If a file ain't saved somewhere on the harddrive yet this property doesn't have a value.
Unfortunately though if you try to retrieve it from an unsaved document you will get a popup with an error message - essentially terminating the script.

To workaround that you can wrap the retrieval of `fullName` inside a try-catch block and just add documents to the `openedDocsToProcess` array if the try doesn't fail.

```
var openedDocsToProcess = new Array;
var failed=false;
var temp;
for (var i = 0; i < app.documents.length; i++) 
{
    try 
    {
        failed=false;
        temp=app.documents[i].fullName;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        failed=true;
    }
    if(!failed)
    {
        openedDocsToProcess.push(app.documents[i]);
    }
}
alert(openedDocsToProcess);
```

Comment: One note, when your debugging level is set to `$.level = 1` (1 - Break) or `$.level = 2` (2 - Immediate Break), it gives error in ExtendScript Toolkit CS6 `The document has not yet been saved`. To avoid that, any debuger schould be set to level 0 (0- No Break). More information here: [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Adobe.extendscript-debug) in row debugLevel.